# Adding a conditional to my code causes VueJS code to not render

Tags: python, django, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code in Vue;

```
/* Does early detection on if the user is logged in or not. If the user
is not logged in, this code is passed over. This is done to make rendering
and compilation of the code faster by filtering out unneeded elements. */
// Debug. Brackets will be placed around 'user-home component later'
if djangoUser === "AnonymousUser" {
    Vue.component('user-home', {
        template:  `<div class="">
                        <a href="#" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                            <img class="avatar-img" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300">
                        </a>
                    </div>`,
    });
    var userHomeDiv = new Vue({
        el: "#user-home-div",
    })
}
```

I want to have the conditional there so that if the user isn't logged in, then those elements won't be processed. However, when I add that conditional, whether or not it evaluates to true, it causes all of the custom elements and Vue code to disappear from my HTML. When I remove it, everything works as normal. What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: That's not valid javascript syntax. you need parenthesis around the condition `if (djangoUser === "AnonymousUser") { }`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. I wasn't aware the syntax was wrong because the debugger didn't report any syntax errors.